# h:inputText value is always null after AJAX event

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I use ajax to enable an input text if a certain value of a selectonemenu is selected. Like this:

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="panelFilial">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="perfil" tabindex="5"
                     value="#{actionCadastrarCotacaoDadosCarga.idProduto}"
                     label="#{msg.selecione}" style="width: 145px;"
                     required="false">
        <f:selectItems value="#{actionCadastrarCotacaoDadosCarga.listProdutos}"></f:selectItems>

        <a4j:support ajaxSingle="true" event="onchange"
                     action="#{actionCadastrarCotacaoDadosCarga.direcionarEnableOutros}"
                     onclick="javascript:Richfaces.showModalPanel('progressWaitModalPanel');
                             atualizarImagem();"
                     reRender="panelOutros" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

Here's my backing bean method:

```
public void direcionarEnableOutros() {
    if (this.idProduto.equals(ID_PRODUTO_OUTROS)) {
        this.enableOutros = false;
        this.descricaoProduto = new String();
    } else {
        this.enableOutros = true;
    }
}
```

When I submit my form, the value of the input text is always null. Am I missing something here?

Here's the input text:

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="panelOutros">
    <h:inputText id="outros" tabindex="6" required="false"
                 maxlength="50"
                 value="#{actionCadastrarCotacaoDadosCarga.descricaoProduto}"
                 disabled="#{!actionCadastrarCotacaoDadosCarga.habilitarCampoOutros}">
    </h:inputText>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

Comment: What is the scope of your bean?

Comment: @SalihErikci event scoped

Comment: Whick JSF version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Seam, the problem must be the event scope. Change it to conversation scope.

**Event Scope**

> The event (request) context. Spans a server request, from restore view
>   to render response.

**Conversation Scope**

> The conversation context. Spans multiple requests from the same
>   browser window, demarcated by @Begin and @End methods. A conversation
>   context is propagated by any faces request, or by any request that
>   specifies a conversation id as a request parameter. The conversation
>   context is not available during the restore view phase.

Comment: When i changed the scope, it gave me this error: JSF1054: (Phase ID: PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3, View ID: /pages/negociacao/cotacao/CadastrarCotacaoDadosGerais.xhtml) Exception thrown during phase execution: javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@2718b62e]

Answer (score 0):

In JSF 2.x you can make use of `@ViewScoped` to makee your bean alive while the user interacts with the same view e.g. ajax requests. In JSF 1.x, there's no `@ViewScoped`, so you had to store and remove the data from view state or even session scope manually. Still, since you're using RichFaces, you can make use of `@KeepAlive` annotation, which works very similar to `@ViewScoped` from JSF 2.

Just do this:

```
@KeepAlive
public class ActionCadastrarCotacaoDadosCarga {
    //bean definition here...
}
```

And make sure **the beans is configured in request scope**:

```
<managed-bean-name>actionCadastrarCotacaoDadosCarga</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>location.of.your.bean.ActionCadastrarCotacaoDadosCarga</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
                 <!-- ^-IMPORTANT-^ -->
</managed-bean>
```